# Liquibase generateChangeLog command - generating changelog with insert statements

Tags: oracle, db2, liquibase, dml

To generate insert statements from my databases (oracle,db2) i've used liquibase generateChangeLog command with argument

> --diffTypes="data"

This command generate correct xml with insert statements, however this is not aware of foreign constraints, so I cannot use this file to again to fill my databases. Similar problems has been described here : [Is there a way to generate Liquibase data in the right order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487693/is-there-a-way-to-generate-liquibase-data-in-the-right-order). The proposed workaround unfortunatelly is not possibile for my databases, because there is no any command to switch of constraint checks.

My question is, if exists any other solution to this problem ? Why can I generate data insert statements changelog, but cannot use it because of foreign key constraints ?

Comment: Its a guess but I think this is simply not implemented in liquibase. Might be too difficult to read all RI and then setup the correct order so RI is satisfied. You can order it yourself, though. Prime idea of liquibase is to have your database structure setup. The `generateChangeLog` commands are there to help you but liquibase is not meant to be a tool to load and unload the contents of your database on a regular basis. (Unless Nathan proves my assumption to be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jens is right in the comment. Liquibase has no way of determining dependencies because the main use case is tracking ran changeSets. GenerateChangeLog is a useful capability but it is not intended to handle all cases and managing dependencies is a complex task that is definitely out of scope.

My normal recommendation is that the output of generateChangeLog should be considered a useful first step for working with the changeLog and if you have dependency issues just reorder the changeSets before executing them. If there many of them, you may want to write a script to reorder them based on your knowledge of your dependencies.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i did.  I reorder it manually - I just divide my generateChangeLog in three xml files. One is pure DDL, second DML and last one is DDL with foreign constraints. I organized this master changelog file in that way that first is DDL, second DML and third is DDL with foreign constraints. So when i'm adding a data in DML there's no constraints, which are added in third file. This is my workaround for lack of switching off constraint check command in my db.

Answer (score 0):

If you can export schema + data, a good solution is separate DDL, DML and this part of DDL that create the constraints. You have to reorder those in the following order:

1. DDL (without constraints)
2. DML (data)
3. DDL (the constraints removed from step 1)

It requires a little bit of manual editing but you'll have to do it once for your project.

And, as a side note, for you next project, start using liquibase from the start, this way you will never encounter this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The jailer export liquidbase feature is excellent for this.  It generates a change log in topological order.

http://jailer.sourceforge.net/